# Incosistent charges and magnetic moments between SCF and PDOS calculations in Quantum Espresso

Tags: quantum-espresso

I have a system of 5 layers of an element + 1 layer of another one, I want the relaxed position of the last layer, and once I have it, proceed to calculate the pdos. I am performing simulations in the order:

- Relax
- SCF with the new position
- NSCF (with 4x the number of k-points)
- PDOS

The SCF output has magnetic moments and charge per site, the PDOS gives a `*.pdos.dat.lowdin` file with the same information.

My problem is that the charges and magnetic moments are different on the SCF and PDOS outputs.

**Which ones should I trust? Why would they be different?**

SCF output:

```
Magnetic moment per site:
atom:    1    charge:   10.8246    magn:    0.0110    constr:    0.0000
atom:    2    charge:   10.8934    magn:    0.0059    constr:    0.0000
atom:    3    charge:   10.9088    magn:   -0.0009    constr:    0.0000
atom:    4    charge:   10.9105    magn:    0.0414    constr:    0.0000
atom:    5    charge:   10.9245    magn:   -0.2424    constr:    0.0000
atom:    6    charge:   13.5294    magn:    3.5015    constr:    0.0000
```

`*.pdos.dat.lowdin`

```
 Atom #   1: total charge =  12.9768, s =  2.3048, p =  6.7101, d =  3.9619,
             spin up      =   6.4972, s =  1.1526,                          
             spin up      =   6.4972, p =  3.3561,                          
             spin up      =   6.4972, d =  1.9885,                          
             spin down    =   6.4796, s =  1.1522,                          
             spin down    =   6.4796, p =  3.3540,                          
             spin down    =   6.4796, d =  1.9734,                          
             polarization =   0.0177, s =  0.0004, p =  0.0021, d =  0.0151,
 Atom #   2: total charge =  13.0022, s =  2.2288, p =  6.8375, d =  3.9359,
             spin up      =   6.5058, s =  1.1145,                          
             spin up      =   6.5058, p =  3.4196,                          
             spin up      =   6.5058, d =  1.9717,                          
             spin down    =   6.4964, s =  1.1143,                          
             spin down    =   6.4964, p =  3.4180,                          
             spin down    =   6.4964, d =  1.9642,                          
             polarization =   0.0094, s =  0.0003, p =  0.0016, d =  0.0075,
 Atom #   3: total charge =  13.0153, s =  2.2252, p =  6.8123, d =  3.9778,
             spin up      =   6.5078, s =  1.1122,                          
             spin up      =   6.5078, p =  3.4082,                          
             spin up      =   6.5078, d =  1.9874,                          
             spin down    =   6.5075, s =  1.1131,                          
             spin down    =   6.5075, p =  3.4041,                          
             spin down    =   6.5075, d =  1.9904,                          
             polarization =   0.0003, s = -0.0009, p =  0.0042, d = -0.0030,
 Atom #   4: total charge =  13.0454, s =  2.2269, p =  6.8300, d =  3.9885,
             spin up      =   6.5563, s =  1.1150,                          
             spin up      =   6.5563, p =  3.4206,                          
             spin up      =   6.5563, d =  2.0208,                          
             spin down    =   6.4891, s =  1.1119,                          
             spin down    =   6.4891, p =  3.4094,                          
             spin down    =   6.4891, d =  1.9678,                          
             polarization =   0.0673, s =  0.0031, p =  0.0112, d =  0.0530,
 Atom #   5: total charge =  13.5800, s =  2.3248, p =  7.1741, d =  4.0811,
             spin up      =   6.5896, s =  1.1552,                          
             spin up      =   6.5896, p =  3.5647,                          
             spin up      =   6.5896, d =  1.8696,                          
             spin down    =   6.9904, s =  1.1696,                          
             spin down    =   6.9904, p =  3.6094,                          
             spin down    =   6.9904, d =  2.2115,                          
             polarization =  -0.4008, s = -0.0144, p = -0.0446, d = -0.3418,
 Atom #   6: total charge =  14.2291, s =  2.6028, p =  5.9944, d =  5.6320,
             spin up      =   8.9997, s =  1.3448,                          
             spin up      =   8.9997, p =  2.9975,                          
             spin up      =   8.9997, d =  4.6574,                          
             spin down    =   5.2294, s =  1.2580,                          
             spin down    =   5.2294, p =  2.9969,                          
             spin down    =   5.2294, d =  0.9746,                          
             polarization =   3.7702, s =  0.0868, p =  0.0006, d =  3.6828,
 Spilling Parameter:   0.0019
```

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: They both use the same scheme for charge calculation?

Comment: Hello @Camps, thanks. What do you mean by scheme? The inputs of the relax, scf, and nscf files are the same except for the `calculation=<relax/scf/nscf>` field, and for the nscf calculation I increase the number of kpoints. For the pdos my input is simply 
`&projwfc                 
  prefix='run',          
  outdir='./out',        
  Emin=0,                
  Emax=17,               
  DeltaE=0.05            
  filproj='slab.pdos.dat'
/                        `

Comment: @Camps do you think is related to how the Lowdin charges are calculated? Maybe the method is different than in the scf calculation

Comment: It could be possible. It is known that different charge calculation methods give (very) different results. Take a look here for different calculation methods [https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1439/24](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1439/24)

Comment: Good to see some discussion here, but if the system asks you to switch from comments to chat, please do **not** click the button, instead chat in the Quantum ESPRESSO room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117642/quantum-espresso

Comment: @UriAceves did the last comment by Camps help?

Comment: @NikeDattani It was a great reference by Camps indeed. It lead me in the correct direction

Comment: @UriAceves Does that mean that you've found an answer to your original problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a valid question.

As the [documentation of `projwfc.x` explains](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PROJWFC.html), it computes the [Löwdin charges](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1439/what-are-the-types-of-charge-analysis/1465#1465).

However, the [documentation of `pw.x`](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html) seems to be silent on the scheme used to compute the charges reported by the SCF calculation.

Luckily, Quantum ESPRESSO is open-source, so you can look at [the source](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e) and work back from the `Magnetic moment per site` string => `PP/src/report_mag.f90` => `get_locals.f90` => `make_pointslist.f90`.
You find what you've been looking for in the documentation of the `make_pointslist` subroutine:

> This initialization is needed in order to integrate charge (or magnetic moment) in a sphere around the atomic positions.
> This can be used to simply monitor these quantities during the scf
> cycles or in order to calculate constraints on these quantities.

> If the integration radius r_m is not provided in input, it is
> calculated here. The integration is a sum over all points in real
> space with
>
> - the weight 1, if they are closer than $r_m$ to an atom
>   and
> - $(1 - (\text{distance}-r_m)/(0.2*r_m) )$ if $( r_m < \text{distance}<1.2*r_m )$.

The radius $r_m$ is determined as

> ... set the radius r_m to a value a little smaller than the
> minimum
> distance divided by 2*1.2 (so no point in space can belong to more than one atom)

I.e. the charge reported by the SCF calculation is a weighted integration of the electronic charge in a sphere around the nucleus.
The formula looks empirical, and the result is probably not comparable to quantities computed by other DFT codes.